# Calling boost::asio::io_service::run from a std::thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a class which handles my connection that has a boost::asio::io_service member. I'm wanting to call io_service::run() from a std::thread, but I am running into compilation errors.

```
std::thread run_thread(&boost::asio::io_service, std::ref(m_io_service));
```

Does not work. I see various examples out there for doing this using boost::thread, but I am wanting to stick to std::thread for this. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two ways as I have known, one is to create std::thread by lambda.

```
std::thread run_thread([&]{ m_io_service.run(); });
```

Another is to create boost::thread with boost::bind

```
boost::thread run_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, boost::ref(m_io_service)));
```

Comment: Lambda is the way to go here, thanks! Definitely the cleanest looking solution.

Comment: *io_context.run()* can be used instead of io_service.run().

Answer (score 1):

Just extending a bit on @cbel's answer. Another way of doing it if you (for whatever reason) would like to avoid boost::thread and lambdas:

```
std::thread run_thread(
    std::bind(static_cast<size_t(boost::asio::io_service::*)()>(
        &boost::asio::io_service::run), std::ref(m_io_service)));
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, both options for the answer marked as the solution did result in exceptions.

What did it for me was:

```
boost::thread run_thread([&] { m_io_service.run(); });
```

instead of

```
std::thread run_thread([&]{ m_io_service.run(); });
```